# How can I know what broke why an Android fragment won't load?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an Android app with quite a few `activities` and even more `fragments`.

I want to swap places of a `Button` and a `TextView`.

Regardless of whether I move them in the `GUI editor`, or move the text in the `XML file`, it causes the *app to crash* when I open that `fragment`.

How do I find out what goes wrong so that I can fix it?

A breakpoint on this line will stop before an exception. A breakpoint after this line will throw an exception.

```
    ((Button) v.findViewById(R.id.invite_button_2)).setOnClickListener(mMethodButtonListener);
```

All I get is this exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
```

*And this stack trace:*

```
 <code>
    Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception RuntimeException))  
    ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 2425    
        ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 2483 
        ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 171    
        ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 1297  
        ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 102    
        Looper.loop() line: 157 
        ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 5506    
        Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
        Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 515  
        ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 1265 
        ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 1081    
        NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]  
    </code>
```

Comment: post your code and i will point out the error

Comment: once clean your project and try again,if not work post your code.

Comment: You are `casting` your `Button` wrongly. Shpw your code so we can help

Comment: But I didn't change the code?

Comment: It 'd be better if you show your code to find where the problem is!

Comment: Looks like you didn't clean/rebuild your project, like Nag said

Comment: Nag, you are right. Feel free to post an answer.